React Native fetching works with localhost but not with IP | MongoDB | AWS EC2
I'm currently working on a React Native project (developing on IOS) and using AWS EC2 and MongoDB for it. I've followed a few tutorials and managed to successfully deploy my backend. At least that's what I assume, because when I enter a route under my public IP address in the browser, the page is found. Everything works fine under localhost. Therefore, I strongly believe that the issue doesn't lie with fetching. I've also tried Axios, but encountered the same error: "Network request failed". However, when I try to test a route using the Simulator, I always get "Network request failed". As if there is no connection to the backend at all. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any additional logs related to this. I've often read that you need to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true in the Info.plist, but unfortunately, that didn't change anything either. I suspect that there's just a fundamental detail missing here, which I simply don't know. I'm quite new to this topic and would like to know the structure for uploading the backend. Perhaps the error lies here, as I've uploaded the entire app and not just the backend. Additionally, I've allowed incoming traffic on port 3000 in the rules for incoming data traffic. I will provide more details if needed.
Code for Login fetching:
const handleLogin = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const userData = {
            email,
            password,
        };

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://IP:3000/api/login', {
    
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(userData),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorText = await response.text();
                console.error(`Fehler-Status: ${response.status}`);
                console.error(`Fehler-Antwort: ${errorText}`);
                throw new Error(`Server antwortete mit Fehler: ${response.status}`);
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
            setIsLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate('homescreen');
        } catch (error) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            Alert.alert('Login fehlgeschlagen', error.message);
        }
    };

server.js:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const emailRoutes = require('./routes/emailRoutes');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("Erfolgreich mit MongoDB verbunden"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Fehler bei der Verbindung mit MongoDB:", err));


app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api', userRoutes); // router.post routes are not found
app.use('/api', emailRoutes);

app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "success Yay!" }); //Is found in Browser
});

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}.`);
});


userRoutes.js:
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../model/User');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const user = new User({
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          email: req.body.email,
          instagramUsername: req.body.instagramUsername,
          phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
          password: req.body.password,
          EXP_firstName: req.body.EXP_firstName,
          EXP_lastName: req.body.EXP_lastName,
          EXP_phoneNumber: req.body.EXP_phoneNumber,
          EXP_instagramUsername: req.body.EXP_instagramUsername,
          verification: req.body.verification,
      });

      const savedUser = await user.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user || user.password !== password) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Ungültige Anmeldeinformationen.' });
    }
    
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'fallbackSecret', { expiresIn: '48h' });


    res.json({ token }); // Sende das Token zurück
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get('/user/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Benutzer nicht gefunden.' });
    }
    const userResponse = {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      instagramUsername: user.instagramUsername,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
      EXP_firstName: user.EXP_firstName,
      EXP_lastName: user.EXP_lastName,
      EXP_phoneNumber: user.EXP_phoneNumber,
      EXP_instagramUsername: user.EXP_instagramUsername,
      userMessage: user.userMessage, 
      
    };
    res.json(userResponse);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Fehler beim Abrufen des Benutzers.' });
  }
});

router.post('/usermessage', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId, message } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Benutzer nicht gefunden.' });
    }
    user.userMessage = message;
    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Benutzerbotschaft erfolgreich gespeichert.' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Fehler beim Speichern der Benutzerbotschaft.' });
  }
});


module.exports = router;

I've checked whether it has anything to do with SSL, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I've tried older versions of React, but with no success. Additionally, I've searched through seemingly every related post for solutions. Especially because I couldn't find anything, I believe I'm missing a fundamental detail

Fixed it: Don't just set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true, Add the following to Info.plist:<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>     <dict>       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>       <true/>       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>       <dict>         <key>localhost</key>         <dict>           <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>           <true/>         </dict>       </dict>     </dict> 
